# Sum of independent standard normal and chi square with one degree of freedom

Tags: probability, statistics, convolution

I need to calculate the distribution of the sum of two independent random variable: the first is a standard normal and the second is a chi square with one degree of freedom. I know that the sum has density given by the convolution between the respective densities, but i have trouble figuring out what this calculation leads to.
Can anyone help me?